# Sending httprequest in javascript

Tags: javascript, http

I have a local server running which returns a dictionary of form {'test' : 'string'} on URL localhost:5000/test . I want to make a request to it using javascript and display the response on console. I am using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
          <title>sending http request</title>
    </head>

    <body>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "localhost:5000/test", true);
            xhr.send();
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
          </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

however When I open the html file in my browser, I get 'NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL:' error displayed on my console on the line where the request in send.

Comment: add the protocol, ie `http://` to your url

Comment: I am getting error ' Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/test. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). '

Comment: I also added header xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); to solve the issue, but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try prepending http:// to your request URL:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/test", true);
        xhr.send();
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: i am getting error 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/test. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).'

Comment: This answers the issue mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** in server script, its pretty may works.

Example: If you are using PHP as server side script use below code

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

**Note:** URL has to prepend with "http://" or "https://"

Comment: I am doing in javascript and appended line ` xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); ` but still the same issue.